# OpenGL creating render context fail

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm writing some OpenGL 3 program on C++, and now i have an issue on my laptop Lenovo Thinkpad e320 (Intel HD Graphics 3000). It works fine on my PC (ATI Radeon HD 5870).

Code near the error is following:

```
bool GLWindowCreate(const char *title, int width, int height, bool fullScreen){
...
    g_hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(g_hDC, 0, attribs);
    if (!g_hRC || !wglMakeCurrent(g_hDC, g_hRC))
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Creating render context fail (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
...
}
```

All compiles fine and i saw this error in log file.

I'm using Windows 8 (both on PC and laptop). Graphic card on laptop supports OpenGL 3. I have found some answer about same problem that i need to turn off hardware acceleration, but it seems there is no way to do this in Win 8.

**Added:**

Whole window create function:

```
bool GLWindowCreate(const char *title, int width, int height, bool fullScreen)
{
    ASSERT(title);
    ASSERT(width > 0);
    ASSERT(height > 0);

    WNDCLASSEX            wcx;
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    RECT                  rect;
    HGLRC                 hRCTemp;
    DWORD                 style, exStyle;
    int                   x, y, format;

    memset(&g_window, 0, sizeof(g_window));

    memset(&g_input, 0, sizeof(g_input));

    PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB = NULL;

    // attributes for OpenGL context
    int attribs[] =
    {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB,         WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,  WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0
    };

    // timer init
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&g_qpc);
    ASSERT(g_qpc.QuadPart > 0);

    g_timerFrequency = 1.0 / g_qpc.QuadPart;

    g_hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    memset(&wcx, 0, sizeof(wcx));
    wcx.cbSize        = sizeof(wcx);
    wcx.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc   = (WNDPROC)GLWindowProc;
    wcx.hInstance     = g_hInstance;
    wcx.lpszClassName = GLWINDOW_CLASS_NAME;
    wcx.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcx.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcx))
    {
        LOG_ERROR("RegisterClassEx fail (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    style   = WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
    exStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;

    x = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - width)  / 2;
    y = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - height) / 2;

    rect.left   = x;
    rect.right  = x + width;
    rect.top    = y;
    rect.bottom = y + height;

    AdjustWindowRectEx (&rect, style, FALSE, exStyle);

    // creating window
    g_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(exStyle, GLWINDOW_CLASS_NAME, title, style, rect.left, rect.top,
        rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, NULL, NULL, g_hInstance, NULL);

    if (!g_hWnd)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("CreateWindowEx fail (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

        // get window descriptor
    g_hDC = GetDC(g_hWnd);

    if (!g_hDC)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("GetDC fail (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nSize      = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion   = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags    = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 24;

    // get pixel format
    format = ChoosePixelFormat(g_hDC, &pfd);
    if (!format || !SetPixelFormat(g_hDC, format, &pfd))
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Setting pixel format fail (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    // creating temp context
    // to get wglCreateContextAttribsARB function
    hRCTemp = wglCreateContext(g_hDC);
    if (!hRCTemp || !wglMakeCurrent(g_hDC, hRCTemp))
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Сreating temp render context fail (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    OPENGL_GET_PROC(PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC, wglCreateContextAttribsARB);

    // delete temp context
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRCTemp);

    // creating OpenGL 3 context
    g_hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(g_hDC, 0, attribs);
    if (!g_hRC || !wglMakeCurrent(g_hDC, g_hRC))
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Creating render context fail (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    int major, minor;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor);
    LOG_DEBUG("OpenGL render context information:\n"
        "  Renderer       : %s\n"
        "  Vendor         : %s\n"
        "  Version        : %s\n"
        "  GLSL version   : %s\n"
        "  OpenGL version : %d.%d\n",
        (const char*)glGetString(GL_RENDERER),
        (const char*)glGetString(GL_VENDOR),
        (const char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION),
        (const char*)glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION),
        major, minor
    );

    if (!OpenGLInitExtensions())
        return false;

    GLWindowSetSize(width, height, fullScreen);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: We need to see more of your context creation code to know what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have accidentally found a decision. Problem was there:

```
int attribs[] =
    {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB,         WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,  WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0
    };
```

Intel HD Graphics 3000 supports only OpenGL 3.1, not 3.3, so i have had to change

```
WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
```

to

```
WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 1,
```

Thanks everyone and sorry for worry, hope my problem solution will help someone